# Check space for 2 fields

Tags: javascript

I have two fields like this :

- "DisneyLand-Paris"
- "DisneyLand-Paris "

On title has no space before the last word. The other has a space, and so this two titles are not considered like same title.

In my app I want to say `it's the same titles` with space or not space after the word.

How can I do this please ?

Comment: you should apply String.trim() to compare them.

Comment: You can compare use `trim` before comparing them. But honestly the scenario is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim):

```js
const title1 = "DisneyLand-Paris";
const title2 = "DisneyLand-Paris ";
const trimmed = title2.trim();

console.log(title1 === title2); // false
console.log(title1 === trimmed); // true
```

So you could do:

```js
// Trim and compare both strings, and report the result.
function compareTitles(title1, title2) {
  if (title1.trim() === title2.trim()) {
    console.log("It's the same titles!");
  }
}

compareTitles("DisneyLand-Paris", "DisneyLand-Paris "); // It's the same titles! 
compareTitles("DisneyLand-Paris ", "DisneyLand-Paris"); // It's the same titles!
```

Comment: Oh thanks !! But can I do this if it's in a list of strings so (my validation code is with a list of strings...)

Comment: @SarahB You can use the same method, but you might need some additional logic to iterate through the list(s). Are you trying to compare two lists, or are you trying compare all strings in a single list?

Comment: Yeah it's good. I'm a backend developer and I help my team with react Js ^^ I've not the right vocabulary and logic but... cool :) really thanks !!

Comment: @SarahB No problem! Please feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use trim() method

```
  const string1 = "DisneyLand-Paris";
  const string2 = "DisneyLand-Paris ";
  const string3 = "";
  if(string1 === string2.trim()){
      string3 = `it's the same titles ` ; //here you have to use template literals because of it’s
      console.log(string3);
  }
```